java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 (Error)
I need help with this code. I kept having this kind of error but I don't know the reason.
        String nam = name.getText();
        String number = num.getText();
        String pass = password.getText();
        String mail = email.getText();
        try{
            Statement s = db.mycon().createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO user (full_name, phone_number, password, email) VALUES ('"+nam+"','"+number+"','"+pass+"','"+mail+"')");
            Success SuccessFrame = new Success();
            SuccessFrame.setVisible(true);
            SuccessFrame.pack();
            SuccessFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.dispose();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
        name.setText("");
        num.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        email.setText("");

I don't see anymore mistakes in my value of column but still I get this error whenever I run the program.
Help me to resolve this problem please.

Make it a lot easier on yourself by using PreparedStatement::setString etc.

Does any of the values you concatenate contain apostrophes and commas? But as g00se says, use a PreparedStatement with placeholders (parameters) and explicitly set the values with its setXXX methods. Your current code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection.

Rather than creating a statement by yourself, use PreparedStatement.
I have found the below stackoverflow chain which guides for using the same.
How to use PreparedStatement with JDBC

You could improve your answer by providing a small example. Note that you can [edit] your answer.
